# Flash ADC - Why R/2 at the ends of the resistor ladder?

Tags: adc, voltage-divider

Why to use R/2 on the ends of the resistor ladder instead of using just R?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps if you calculated the voltages at the 3 points in the resistor ladder it might become more obvious.

Comment: The ladder goes as 0.167Vref - 0.5Vref - 0.833Vref, I am still not sure why not just split it by 4xR, which would create 0.25Vref, 0.5Vref, 0.75Vref

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why to use R/2 on the ends of the resistor ladder instead of using just R?

Because it is better to have a max. error of \$\pm \frac{1}{2}\$ bit:

[image]
[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter)

It looks wasteful with just 4 codes, but this trades off 2 *half bits* in the whole range for a represented range that crosses the origin. See below for a 0V to 10V input range:

[image]

The input values below 0V and above 10V may never occur for \$V_{ref}=10V\$, but the average error **due to quantization** is zero.